# How to log-in via TTY by instead of GDM?

Tags: login-screen, gdm, tty

I want my Ubuntu box to boot directly into a tty login screen and after it does that I want it to automatically run `startx` how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't mean to be nosy, but why do this? If you want to end up in a graphic environment by default, why not use a display manager?

Comment: to deter thiefs

Comment: I doubt that thieves will be interested in the contents of your computer, and if they are i'm sure the can find out hot boot from a live-cd. If you fear for you data's security encrypt you disk.

Comment: its not my data I'm worried about its the physical computer if it boots into a text based environment they'll assume its broken and not take it (or so I'm hoping)

Comment: I doubt a thief will even touch the power button

Answer (score 8):

What txwikinger said, but then to make it automatically run `startx` when you login, edit `~/.bash_profile`  -- that file is only executed on login shells, not in normal terminal emulators that you open on your desktop.

EDIT:
`~/.profile` if you don't use `bash`

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the automatic start of the X-server by disabling the `start on` lines in `gdm.conf` and/or `kdm.conf`. This way upstart will not automatically start the X-server.

After logging in into the tty, you can just start the appropriate login session via `sudo start gdm` or `sudo start kdm`. Or if you rather want the traditional x, you could run startx, if it is configured such that you can do the things you want to do from that.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out from the grub boot menu you can press `e` over any entry to edit its configuration.  If you do this over the ubuntu entry there is a line that starts with the word `linux` and ends with something like `ttyhandoff=7`.  Changing this to `ttyhandoff=1` does what you would expect.

Apparently you could also append `text` to the end of this line.